# Advertisement system with allowed click encouragement

Tags: google-adsense, advertising

Is there any advertisement system (like AdSense) that would allow me to encourage the visitors on my page to click the ad?

The pay doesn't need to be as high as in AdSense, it's only important that I'm not braking the rules by doing so.

Comment: Are you asking for an ad network that encourages click fraud (clicking with no actual interest in the advertised product, but simply to help the publisher get more PPC money)?

Comment: Actually, I know it sounds stupid, but I would like to have something like: "You can support me by clicking the ad" on my website :)

Comment: Why not "you can support me by checking out my sponsors?" That would encourage _legit_ clickthrus and wouldn't be interpreted by anyone as clickfraud promotion.

Comment: You're saying I can refer to the random ads on my page as my sponsors? I don't think Google AdSense would like that, since there might be an exceptional high click-rate.

Comment: Any business/persons that support you financially to allow you to provide a free service is by definition a "sponsor". That said, Google doesn't like publishers drawing _any_ kind of "unnatural" attention to ads. But there are other networks that probably don't care if you encourage legitimate click-throughs. The point is, you should be encouraging users to take a look at the sponsor's product, not simply encouraging users to click on the ad. The latter has no value to advertisers.

Answer (score 1):

[Commission Junction](http://www.cj.com/) encourages affiliate relationships which might be closer to what you're looking for (i.e. advertising integrated with your site content) though you should look at the disclosures necessary to comply with [FTC guidelines](http://www.ftc.gov/bcp/edu/pubs/business/adv/bus71.shtm) if you are operating in the United States.